# If the $m-1$ first derivatives of a rational function vanish at a point, does the function have a zero of order $m$ at that point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{2}$ be a projective smooth algebraic curve, and let $$
\alpha:K(C)\rightarrow K(C)
$$
be a derivation, i.e. $\alpha$ is a $K$-linear map such that 
$$
\alpha(fg)=f\alpha(g)+g\alpha(f)
$$
for every $f,g\in K(C)$, where $K(C)$ is the field of functions of $C$. Let us suppose that 
$$
f(p)=\alpha(f)(p)=\alpha^{2}(f)(p)=\cdots=\alpha^{m-1}(f)(p)=0
$$
for certain $f\in K(C),p\in  C$. Is it true that $f$ has a zero of order (at least) $m$ at $p$? In case it is not, what conditions do we have to impose for the result to hold?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you mentioned is correct. The order of the zero can be higher because more derivations can vanish.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you know of a book where this result is proven, or a sketch of its proof?

Comment: I only know a proof for univariate functions $f(x)$, no idea whether there is a generalized proof for multivariate functions. The proof idea should be similar.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could show me. Thank you!